# Dúvida sobre threads

Tags: java, thread

Tenho duas classes.

Uma possui uma `thread` para o download de anexos de e-mails e a outra possui uma `thread` para a conversão de arquivos `xml` para `csv`.

Dei um start nessas duas `threads` em outra `classe`. A `thread` dos e-mails tem que ficar esperando por novos e-mails e a outra `thread` tem que converter os arquivos que tem numa pasta dentro do projeto, e se vier algum novo através da `thread` que faz o download dos anexos, ela também tem que converter esse arquivo.

Alguma dica de como posso fazer isso?

Eu tenho as `threads` e tudo pronto. Mas não sei como organizá-las de forma que o que eu quero funcione.

`LeitorEmail`

*obs: esta é uma classe para fazer a leitura de e-mails e download de anexos para o computador. O código teria que ficar em uma thread que permanecesse rodando direto ou que rodasse de acordo com algum tempo estipulado para receber novos arquivos.*

```
public class LeitorEmail {
    // pasta onde os arquivos XML serão salvos
    public static final String pastaXML = "arquivos-xml";
    public static final String imap = "imaps"; 
    // endereço do servidor de hospedagem do gmail 
    public static final String host = "imap.gmail.com"; 
    // porta para acessar o gmail
    public static final int porta = 993; 
    // arquivo de mensagens do e-mail
    public static final String arquivoMSG = "Inbox"; 
    // e-mail de onde os arquivos serão pegos
    public static final String login = "xxxx@gmail.com.br"; 
    // senha
    public static final String senha = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
    // pasta onde ficam os arquivos dentro do e-mail
    public static final String pastaPrincipal = "Inbox"; 

    private Store store = null;
    private Folder folder = null;
    private Message message = null;
    private Message[] messages = null;
    private Object msgObj = null;
    private String sender = null;
    private String subject = null;
    private Multipart multipart = null;
    private Part part = null;
    private String contentType = null;

    public LeitorEmail() throws MessagingException {
        processMail();
    }

    /**
     * Processa o e-mail
     * 
     */
    public void processMail() throws MessagingException {
        try {
            store = conexaoServidorEMail();
            folder = getPastaCaixaEntrada(store);
            messages = folder.getMessages();

            for (int messageNumber = 0; messageNumber < messages.length; messageNumber++) {
                message = messages[messageNumber];
                msgObj = message.getContent();

                // Determine o tipo de email
                if (msgObj instanceof Multipart) {

                    subject = message.getSubject();
                    multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

                    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {

                        part = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                        // pegando um tipo do conteúdo
                        contentType = part.getContentType();

                        String fileName2 = part.getFileName();
                        if(fileName2 != null) {
                            System.out.println(messageNumber + " " + fileName2 + " | " + message.getSubject());
                        }
                        fileName2 = null;
                        // teste para saber o tipo de conteúdo (PDF, PLAIN TEXT, XML...)
                        //System.out.println("content type: " + contentType);
                        //System.out.println();

                        // Tela do conteúdo
                        if (contentType.startsWith("text/plain")) {
                            System.out.println("É só um e-mail comum... :|");
                        } else {
                            // TASK: FIXME 
                            // validação XML
                            if (contentType.startsWith("TEXT/XML") && validarXML(part) == true){
                                System.out.println("*************************************************************************************************************");
                                System.out.println("                                          Salvando arquivo...                                                ");
                                salvarArquivo(part);
                                System.out.println("                                          Arquivo Salvo! :3                                                  ");
                                System.out.println("*************************************************************************************************************");
                            }
//                          String fileName = part.getFileName();
//                          @SuppressWarnings("unused")
//                          Message[] mensagensXML = separaMensagensXML(i, fileName);

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    sender = ((InternetAddress) message.getFrom()[0]).getPersonal();
                    if (sender == null) {
                        sender = ((InternetAddress) message.getFrom()[0]).getAddress();
                    }
                    // Get the subject information
                    subject = message.getSubject();
                }
            }
            // Fecha a pasta
            folder.close(true);
            // Histório de mensagens
            store.close();
            System.out.println("Terminado");
        } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FolderNotFoundException e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ReadOnlyFolderException e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StoreClosedException e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            store.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recebe o anexo e valida se é um XML, se sim ele salva o arquivo em uma
     * pasta
     * 
     * @param part
     * @return
     * @throws MessagingException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private boolean validarXML(Part part) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        String fileName = part.getFileName();
        if (fileName != null) {
            int tamanhoString = fileName.length() - 3;
            if (fileName.substring(tamanhoString).equals("xml")) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * @author Waffle-Chan
     * @Data 26.01.2017
     * @Função Salva o arquivo em uma pasta
     * 
     */
    private void salvarArquivo(Part part) throws IOException, MessagingException {  
        // variável que armazena o caminho da pasta onde o arquivo será salvo de acordo com o tipo dele
        String caminhoPasta = "";

        // vai para a pasta
        caminhoPasta = pastaXML;
        System.out.println(caminhoPasta + part.getFileName());

        // O arquivo é aberto em uma FileOutputStream . Caso o arquivo não exista, ele é criado. (neste caso, é criado)
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminhoPasta + part.getFileName());
        // É criado um ObjectOutputStream a partir da stream anterior.
        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        // o objeto "obj" recebe o conteúdo do arquivo xml vindo do e-mail
        Object obj = part.getContent();
        // teste: verificar se o arquivo está vindo completo do e-mail
        //System.out.println(part.getContent());

        try {
            // Ao escrever no ObjectOutputStream, os dados são enviados por meio da FileOutputStream para o arquivo físico.
            stream.writeObject(obj);
            // Por fim, a stream é fechada.
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Acessa a Caixa de Entrada (Inbox)
     * 
     * @param store
     * @return
     * @throws MessagingException
     */
    private Folder getPastaCaixaEntrada(Store store) throws MessagingException {
        Folder folder;
        // pego a pasta principal (Ibox) do e-mail
        folder = store.getFolder(pastaPrincipal);
        // abro a pasta para leitura/escrita, conforme o que será utilizado
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        // retorno a caixa de entrada
        return folder;
    }

    /**
     * Autenticação e conexão com o Servidor de e-mail
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     * @throws MessagingException
     */
    private Store conexaoServidorEMail() throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
        Session session;
        Store store;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        session = Session.getInstance(prop);
        URLName url = new URLName(imap, host, porta, arquivoMSG, login, senha);
        store = session.getStore(url);
        store.connect();

        return store;
    }
}
```

`classe para executar o LeitorEmail`

*obs: aqui estava dentro de uma thread, mas como não consegui fazer o que eu queria, acabei tirando...*

public class ServicoEmail {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
    LeitorEmail leitor =null; 
    try { 
        leitor = new LeitorEmail(); 
    } catch (MessagingException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

}

`ServicoCSV`

*obs: le um arquivo XML e converte para CSV. Esta thread teria que ficar rodando para os arquivos que estão no diretório e se aparecer outro arquivo dentro dele, teria que rodar de novo para este novo arquivo. Como podem ver eu já deixei o código dentro de uma thread...*

```
public class ServicoCSV implements Runnable {
    /** DECLARAÇÃO DE VARIÁVEIS DA CLASSE **/
    // variável utilizada para modificar o nome do arquivo gerado
    public static int num = 0;
    // variável utilizada para armazenar o caminho do arquivo de schema
    static String schema = null;
    // 
    static Leitor.LeitorXML arq;
    // crio um objeto da classe ConversorXMl
    static Conversor.ConversorXML conversor = new Conversor.ConversorXML();
    // variável auxiliar
    static int i;
    // variável utilizada para pegar os arquivos do diretório 
    static File arquivosXML[];
    // 
    static File diretorioArqXML;
    static File diretorioArqXMLPos;

    public void run() {
        /** INICIALIZAÇÃO DE VARIÁVEIS **/
        diretorioArqXML = new File("arquivos-xml");
        // diretorioArqXMLPos = new File ("arquivos-xml");
        // armazeno os arquivos em um vetor de arquivos
        arquivosXML = diretorioArqXML.listFiles();
        // inicializo o contador em 0
        i = 0;

        // enquanto o contador for menor do que o número de arquivos dentro do diretório de arquivos 
        while (i < diretorioArqXML.listFiles().length) {
            // se houver um esquema para o arquivo XML
            if(schemaSource!=null){
                System.out.println (i + " - " + arquivosXML[i].toString());
                //cria o leitor XML para cada arquivo XML no array testando consistencia contra o schema
                arq = new Leitor.LeitorXML(true,schema, arquivosXML[i].toString());
                i++;
            }else{
                //cria o leitor XML para cada arquivo XML no array
                arq = new Leitor.LeitorXML(false, schema, arquivosXML[i].toString());
            }
            try {
                arq.guardaEstruturaXML(arq.doc.getChildNodes());
                arq.ConfereLancamentosXML();

                // chamando os métodos que estão em EscritorXML 
                escritor.converteVetorParaCSV(arq);
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            }

            // incrementando num para passar para o próximo arquivo
            num ++;
        }
```

Comment: Coloque o código que você já tem pronto, assim podemos ajudar você a elaborá-lo

Comment: Sem você colocar o código que você já fez, fica difícil te dizer o que você tem que fazer, o que você tem que alterar e o que você tem que deixar como está.

Comment: @Victor Stafusa eu não tenho permissão para divulgar todo o código, mas tentei deixar mais completo.. =c  obrigada pela ajuda pessoal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WatchService

Você pode criar um [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) para te notificar sempre que algum evento ocorrer no diretório que você está observando. Exemplo:

```
public class WatchServiceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path dir = Paths.get("C:/Caminho/da/pasta/que/voce/quer/acompanhar");
        //Aqui você registra os tipos de evento que quer acompanhar
        //Nesse exemplo, eu coloquei para ser notificado sempre 
        //que um arquivo for criado
        dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        
        WatchKey watchKey = null;
        while (true) {
            watchKey = watcher.poll(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if(watchKey != null) {
                watchKey.pollEvents().stream().forEach(event -> System.out.println(event.context()));
            }
            watchKey.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

[Aqui](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-8-watchservice-api-tutorial/) um guia mais completo.

### Observer

Outra opção é utilizar o padrão de projeto [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Exemplo simples com o seu código:

Crie uma interface que representa a ação que deva ser executada quando o evento de seu interesse ocorrer:

```
public interface ArquivoCriadoListener {
    
    public void acao(String caminho);
}
```

Modifique sua classe `LeitorEmail` para que você possa registrá-los:

```
public class LeitorEmail {
    
    private final List<ArquivoCriadoListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Seus outros atributos
    
    public LeitorEmail(List<ArquivoCriadoListener> listeners) throws MessagingException {
        this.listeners.addAll(listeners);
        processMail();
    }
    
    //Seus outros métodos
    
    //Altere esse método para que ele execute os listeners sempre que o arquivo for salvo
    private void salvarArquivo(Part part) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        //O resto do código que você usa para salvar o aquivo
        
        // O nome do seu arquivo
        String nomeDoArquivo = ...;
        
        listeners.forEach(a -> a.acao(nomeDoArquivo));
    }
}
```

Sua classe `ServicoCSV`:

```
public class ServicoCSV implements ArquivoCriadoListener {

    @Override
    public void acao(String caminho) {
        File file = new File(caminho);
        //aqui você implementa o método de converter o arquivo
    }
    
}
```

Seu `ServicoEmail`:

```
public class ServicoEmail {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        new LeitorEmail(Arrays.asList(new ServicoCSV()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar isso! Muito obrigada pela ajuda :3